# How can I add 'firebase admin' role to Firebase project service accouts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use firebase cloud function for triggger FCM when Firestore has new created. But it has an error "Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions."

I found same error topics at

['An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers' on Firebase Cloud Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72494678/an-error-occurred-when-trying-to-authenticate-to-the-fcm-servers-on-firebase-c)

and there is solution for solving by add role to service account.

But I cannot find the way to add role to service account.

How can I add 'firebase admin' role to Firebase project service accouts?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I add 'firebase admin' role to Firebase project service accouts?

If you don't have `<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` in your [IAM](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/iam-admin/iam?supportedpurview=project,folder,organizationId&_ga=2.75058907.814814821.1654739187-1966793529.1652154324), you can manually add it by clicking the **ADD** button, and then in the **Principal**, you can searh and add the `<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`:

[image]

Lastly, in the **Role***, you can search and add the `roles/firebase admin`. Then click the **SAVE** button, and wait for at least 5-10 minutes before trying to add a new document in your Firebase to make sure that the permission is added.

For more reference, you can check:

1. [Creating and managing custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles)
2. [Manage access to projects, folders, and organizations](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)
3. [Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)

Comment: Hi @RJC, Thank you for your help. After I add new "firebase admin" role to "<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" account, and then test again. The error has remain occur. This is my original error post in StackOverflow before I found your solution [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72427537/how-to-solve-problem-firebase-cloud-messaging-error-in-firebase-cloud-function).

Comment: Since my proposed solution didn't resolve your issue, you can file a support ticket directly to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support).